# Unsure which version of Ruby I have installed on Mountain Lion..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

Hello Ruby/Rails users!

I would like to use the gem 'simplecov' for coverage analysis. I installed the gem but whenver I run tests, I get a message saying simplecov is not activated and cannot be used because I am not using ruby 1.9+

Though, when I run

```
brew which ruby
```

I get:

```
ruby: 1.9.3-p362
```

Which suggests I have ruby 1.9+

But when I run `ruby -v` I get:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

So which version of ruby do I have? And how to I clean my mac repo so that I only have ruby 1.9+ and not the 1.8.7 build?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you do not uninstall system ruby. I'm not 100% sure about osx+ruby, but uninstalling (or replacing) system python on centos will inflict serious damage to your system. Instead you should use RVM/rbenv to install and manage alternate ruby versions.

Comment: RVM/rbenv isn't required, but tbh, if you are doing serious development (i.e. making a job of it), then use one of them instead of my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Both. OS X comes with Ruby 1.8.7 as part of the OS, and removing it is not a good idea (if it is even possible) as it could be required in unexpected places (apps, tools, etc). What you need to do is to change your $PATH to have the 1.9.3 executable before the 1.8.7.

See https://superuser.com/questions/353775/installing-ruby-with-homebrew for more info on changing your path